# additonal parameters for custom_func?

Tags: jqgrid

I want to reuse the following code for custom_func:

```
function validLen(value,colName){
    if(value.length === 8){
        return [true,""];
    }
    else{
        return [false,"fail"];
    }
}
```

I tried giving it an additional parameter as follows:

```
function validLen(value,colName,length){
    if(value.length === length){
        return [true,""];
    }
    else{
        return [false,"fail"];
    }
}
```

And calling it like this:

```
{name:'cntrct_id', editrules:{custom: true, custom_func:validLen(8)} },
```

Didn't work.  The previous code DOES work, but as stated, I want a reusable function.  Is there a workaround for this?  Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you to use

```js
editoptions: { maxlength: 8}
```

instead of the custom validation which you use. In the case the input element will be created with the [maxlength](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp) attribute directly. So the user will not able to type more as characters as specified by `maxlength`.

**UPDATED**: You can't change the interface of any callback function, but you can do share common code of different `custom_func` in the following way. You define your custom validation function having three parameters like

```js
function validLen (value, colName, valueLength) {
    if (value.length === valueLength) {
        return [true, ""];
    }
    else {
        return [false, "fail"];
    }
}
```

and use it in the following way

```js
{
    name: 'cntrct_id',
    editrules: {
        custom: true,
        custom_func: function (value, colName) {
            return validLen(value, colName, 8);
        }
}
```

If you need to use `this` inside of `custom_func` then you can change `return validLen(value, colName, 8);` to `return validLen.call(this, value, colName, 8);`.

Comment: The user needs to enter exactly 8 characters, no more no less.  I have already implemented a maxlength option on that field, but this does not prevent the user from entering less than 8 characters.  The heart of my question is really how to make custom_func type functions reusable rather than how to address this specific problem.

Comment: @MattWall: Look at the **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: Oleg, that makes a lot of sense.  Once again you have provided a clear and logical example.  Thank you.